# php strtotime giving default date

Tags: php, datetime

I want to convert date into another format but its shows default date.

```
$date ='2050-12-12 00:00:00';

echo $product_expire_date = date('Ymd', strtotime($date));
```

It shows the default date 19700101.

Comment: You want to convert to what?

Comment: I want to convert into 'Ymd' format

Answer (score 3):

The valid range of a `timestamp` is typically from `Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC` to `Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC`. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)

http://php.net/strtotime#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes

Answer (score 2):

First of all your date is exceeding [`2038`](http://www.sitepoint.com/is-your-php-application-affected-by-the-y2k38-bug/) and hence you are getting the default date... and if you simply want the date from that string, you can explode the string and echo the first index like

```
$date = explode(' ', '2050-12-12 00:00:00');
echo $date[0]; //Echoes date
echo $date[1]; //Echoes time
```

Comment: No,actullay i want to compare date after converting 

if($product_expire_date <= date('Ymd', strtotime(' +7 day')))
{
}

Comment: @RahulChipad what you exactly want here? do you want to subtract the dates? if they exceed certain seconds, you want to mark the product as expired?

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` and `date()`:

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

(see [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://php.net/date) docs on the PHP site).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$date       =    '2050-12-12 00:00:00';
$newdate     =    explode(" ",$date);
$newdate1    =    explode("-",$newdate[0]);
echo $newdate1[0].$newdate1[1].$newdate1[2];
?>
```